# POST request in GSheet to get a token from API

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

It works with Postman. The POST request gives me my token there. 
But I need it in GoogleScript to get it into my sheet.
I tried this:

```
function getMyToken() {

var playload = {
  email: 'myEmail@mail.com',
  accountName: 'accountName',
  password: 'myPassword',
};

var options = {
  'method':'post',
  'playload':playload
};

var url = 'https://accountName.leankit.com/io/reporting/auth';
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var reqReturn = result.getContentText();
Logger.log(reqReturn); 

var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().
  getSheetByName('TestWithScript').
  getRange(1,1).setValue(reqReturn);
}
```

After run this I receive a mistake:

```
Request failed for https://accountName.leankit.com/io/reporting/auth 
returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad 
Request","message":"child \"email\" fails because [\"email\" is 
required]","validation":{"source":"payload","keys":[... (use 
muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 59, file "Code")
```

I guess I am really close to my solution, apparently the syntax is wrong

Comment: The issue is not directly related to Google Sheets, instead it's about the [URL Fetch service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) which is used to issue HTTP / HTTPS requests and receive responses so it could be have more chances to reach the proper group of experts on [so].

Comment: Try "payload" instead of "playload".

Comment: YES Gorbles. Thanks. That was one of two mistakes. Second one was missing JSON.Parse